# ansible How to make a union of list accross hosts

Tags: ansible

I've got a variable, host_list, which is a different list for all hosts.
I'm looking to a way to make a union of host_list accross hosts.
Meaning, I'd like to have overall_list containing all element of host_list of all host.

Input:

`- fe1: [ "W", "Z" ]
 - be1: [ "Z", "X" ]`

Ouput:
overall_list: [ "W", "Z", "X" }

How can I do so?

Thanks,
Raoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally find it:

```
- name: union list accross hosts 
  set_fact: 
    union_list: "{{ union_list | default([]) | union(hostvars[item]['host_list']) }}" 
  run_once: true 
  with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

two groups in the inventory

```
cat hosts
[group1]
a
b
c
[group2]
b
d
e
f
```

union:

```
ansible -i hosts group1:group2 --list-hosts
  hosts (6):
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple option would be to use json_query

```
- set_fact:
    union_list: "{{ hostvars|json_query('[].host_list')|flatten|unique }}"
```

Comment: Indeed fe1, and be1 are hosts. What I meant is when I've got a different list between 2 hosts, how to get the union os them.